How to fix CSRF token validation while login: PHP and MySQL
I have built a login system for teachers and students that redirects them to the appropriate page after successful login. The user enters their username, password, and selects their account type. They can also check a "Remember Me" option to stay logged in, with the session saved for 30 days.
The problem is that when trying to log in, an "Invalid CSRF token" error message appears, and login fails. I also noticed in the database that when I open my website on the index.php page, a CSRF token is generated. When I navigate to the login page, another token is created in the database.
The first record appears when accessing the website, and the second record is created when navigating to the login page, as shown in the database. The data in the record created on the home page is empty, while the data on the login page is filled in correctly. However, shouldn't any CSRF tokens be created on the home page?
Here is an image of the database:
جدول sessions في قاعدة البيانات مخزن به رمزي CSRF من صفحة index.php و login.php
I use XAMPP for local hosting my website and also tried to provide "https://" connection accross XAMPP but it didn't fix the problem.
I am also using session_handler.php to manage sessions and check_auth.php to check if the user is logged in and their session is stored in the auth_tokens table in the database and I use tauth.php and sauth.php to collect the data of the user if he was a teacher or a student to print them in the dashboard after logging in.
Here is the complete code:
MySQL:
CREATE TABLE auth_tokens (
    id int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    selector varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    hashed_validator varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    expires datetime NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT auth_tokens_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE sessions (
    id int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    data text NOT NULL,
    last_accessed timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE students (
    id int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    guardian_phone varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    gender enum('male','female') NOT NULL,
    level enum('first','second','third') NOT NULL,
    description varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT students_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE teachers (
    id int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title enum('teacher','assistant') NOT NULL,
    subject enum('Arabic','English','French','German','Italian','Physics','Chemistry','Biology','Geology','Mathematics','Philosophy','History','Geography') NOT NULL,
    bio text DEFAULT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT teachers_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE users (
    id int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    first_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    last_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    phone_number varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    account_type enum('teacher','student') NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

db_connect.php:
<?php
//db_connect.php
function getDatabaseConnection() {
    static $conn;

    if (!$conn) {
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "datainfo";
        
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: {$conn->connect_error}");
        }
    }

    return $conn;
}

index.php:
<?php
// index.php
require 'session_handler.php';
require_once 'pages/check_auth.php';
require_once 'pages/db_connect.php';

// get database connection
$conn = getDatabaseConnection();

// Verify session existence (It has already been dealt with in check_auth.php)
$is_logged_in = isset($_SESSION['user_id']); 

// Modified SQL Queries to Count Students and Teachers in One Query
$sqlCounts = "
    SELECT 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN account_type = 'student' THEN 1 END) AS studentCount,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN account_type = 'teacher' THEN 1 END) AS teacherCount
    FROM users";
$resultCounts = $conn->query($sqlCounts);
$rowCounts = $resultCounts->fetch_assoc();
$studentCount = htmlspecialchars($rowCounts['studentCount'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$teacherCount = htmlspecialchars($rowCounts['teacherCount'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
?>

login.php:
<?php
// login.php
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1);

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
    ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1); // Enable cookie_secure only if the connection is over HTTPS.
}

require 'session_handler.php';
require_once 'check_auth.php';
require_once 'db_connect.php';

try {
    $errors = [];
    $conn = getDatabaseConnection();
    
    // Check for CSRF token
    if (empty($_SESSION['csrf_token'])) {
        $_SESSION['csrf_token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
    }
    
    // Check for request POST
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        // Check for CSRF
        if (!isset($_POST['csrf_token']) || $_POST['csrf_token'] !== $_SESSION['csrf_token']) {
            $errors[] = 'Invalid CSRF Token.';
        } else {
            $username = trim($_POST['username']);
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $account_type = $_POST['account_type'];
    
            if (!in_array($account_type, ['teacher', 'student'])) {
                $errors[] = 'Invalid Account Type.';
            }
    
            if (empty($username)) {
                $errors[] = 'Please enter your username.';
            }
            if (empty($password)) {
                $errors[] = 'Please enter your password.';
            }
    
            if (empty($errors)) {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND account_type = ?";
                if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
                    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $account_type);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    
                    if ($result->num_rows === 1) {
                        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                        if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
                            session_regenerate_id(true); // Renew user session
    
                            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
                            $_SESSION['account_type'] = $account_type;
                            $_SESSION['username'] = htmlspecialchars($row['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                            $_SESSION['email'] = htmlspecialchars($row['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                            $_SESSION['first_name'] = htmlspecialchars($row['first_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                            $_SESSION['last_name'] = htmlspecialchars($row['last_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                            $_SESSION['phone_number'] = htmlspecialchars($row['phone_number'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    
                            if ($account_type === 'teacher') {
                                $teacher_query = "SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE id = ?";
                                $teacher_stmt = $conn->prepare($teacher_query);
                                $teacher_stmt->bind_param("i", $row['id']);
                                $teacher_stmt->execute();
                                $teacher_data = $teacher_stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
                                $_SESSION['title'] = htmlspecialchars($teacher_data['title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                                $_SESSION['subject'] = htmlspecialchars($teacher_data['subject'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                                $_SESSION['bio'] = htmlspecialchars($teacher_data['bio'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                            } elseif ($account_type === 'student') {
                                $student_query = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = ?";
                                $student_stmt = $conn->prepare($student_query);
                                $student_stmt->bind_param("i", $row['id']);
                                $student_stmt->execute();
                                $student_data = $student_stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
                                $_SESSION['guardian_phone'] = htmlspecialchars($student_data['guardian_phone'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                                $_SESSION['gender'] = htmlspecialchars($student_data['gender'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                                $_SESSION['level'] = htmlspecialchars($student_data['level'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                            }
    
                            // Set a unique user identification code
                            $token = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
                            setcookie('user_token', $token, time() + 86400 * 30, "/", "", true, true);
                            $_SESSION['user_token'] = $token;
    
                            setcookie('user_token', $token, [
                                'expires' => time() + 86400 * 30,
                                'path' => '/',
                                'secure' => true,
                                'httponly' => true,
                                'samesite' => 'Strict'
                            ]);
    
                            // Processing the "Remember Me" option
                            if (isset($_POST['remember_me'])) {
                                $selector = base64_encode(random_bytes(9));
                                $authenticator = random_bytes(33);
                                $hashedToken = hash('sha256', $authenticator);
                                $expires = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() + 86400 * 30);
                                $userId = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    
                                $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO auth_tokens (selector, hashed_validator, expires, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
                                $stmt = $conn->prepare($insertQuery);
                                $stmt->bind_param("sssi", $selector, $hashedToken, $expires, $userId);
                                $stmt->execute();
    
                                // Set Cookies
                                setcookie('remember_me_selector', $selector, time() + 86400 * 30, '/', '', true, true);
                                setcookie('remember_me_authenticator', base64_encode($authenticator), time() + 86400 * 30, '/', '', true, true);
                            }
    
                            // Redirection based on account type
                            if ($account_type === 'teacher') {
                                sleep(1);
                                header("Location: teacher-dashboard.php");
                            } else {
                                sleep(1);
                                header("Location: student-dashboard.php");
                            }
                            exit();
                        } else {
                            $errors[] = 'Username or Password is Incorrect';
                        }
                    } else {
                        $errors[] = 'This Account is Not Exist';
                    }
                    $stmt->close();
                } else {
                    error_log("Error in preparing statement: {$conn->error}");
                    $errors[] = 'An Error Occurred While Signing You In. Please Try Again Later.';
                }
            }
        }
    }
} catch (\Throwable $th) {
    error_log($th->getMessage());
    $errors[] = $th->getMessage();
    header("Location: error_page.php?error=" . urlencode($th->getMessage()));
    exit();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ar" dir="rtl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/login.css"> 
    <title>login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="text-center mb-5">Login</h2>
            <div class="form-container">
                <form method="post" action="login.php" class="row g-3">
                    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['csrf_token'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="form-floating mb-2">
                            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="username" aria-label="username" autocomplete="username" required>
                            <label for="floatingInput">Username</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="form-floating mb-2">
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="password" aria-label="password" required>
                            <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="form-floating mb-2">
                            <select name="account_type" class="form-select" id="floatingSelect" aria-label="account type">
                                <option value="teacher" selected>Teacher</option>
                                <option value="student">Student</option>
                            </select>
                            <label for="floatingSelect">Account Type</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="rememberMeCheck">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="rememberMeCheck">Remember Me</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php if (!empty($errors)): ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger w-100 text-center" id="error-message" role="alert">
                            <?php foreach ($errors as $error): ?>
                                <?php echo htmlspecialchars($error, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?><br>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <button type="submit" id="login" class="btn btn-primary w-100 focus-ring focus-ring-light py-1 px-2 rounded-2">login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="form-footer mt-3">
                    <p>Forgot Password؟ <a href="reset_password.php">Reset Password</a>.</p>
                    <p>Don't Have an Account؟ <a href="signup.php">Signup Now</a>.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/35b8a1f8f5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("login").focus();
    </script>
</body>
</html>

check_auth.php:
<?php
// check_auth.php
require_once 'db_connect.php';

if (isset($_COOKIE['remember_me_selector']) && isset($_COOKIE['remember_me_authenticator'])) {
    $selector = $_COOKIE['remember_me_selector'];
    $authenticator = base64_decode($_COOKIE['remember_me_authenticator']);
    $token = hash('sha256', $authenticator);

    $conn = getDatabaseConnection();

    $selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM auth_tokens WHERE selector = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($selectQuery);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $selector);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows === 1) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $hashedToken = $row['hashed_validator'];
        $expires = $row['expires'];

        if (hash_equals($hashedToken, hash('sha256', $authenticator)) && $expires > date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
            session_regenerate_id(true);

            $newAuthenticator = random_bytes(33);
            $newHashedToken = hash('sha256', $newAuthenticator);

            $updateQuery = "UPDATE auth_tokens SET hashed_validator = ? WHERE selector = ?";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($updateQuery);
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $newHashedToken, $selector);
            $stmt->execute();

            setcookie('remember_me_authenticator', base64_encode($newAuthenticator), time() + 86400 * 30, '/', '', true, true);
        } else {
            $deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM auth_tokens WHERE selector = ?";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($deleteQuery);
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $selector);
            $stmt->execute();

            setcookie('remember_me_selector', '', time() - 3600, '/', '', true, true);
            setcookie('remember_me_authenticator', '', time() - 3600, '/', '', true, true);
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
}

session_handler.php:
<?php
// session_handler.php
require_once 'db_connect.php';

$conn = getDatabaseConnection();

session_set_save_handler(
    'openSession',
    'closeSession',
    'readSession',
    'writeSession',
    'destroySession',
    'gcSession'
);

function openSession() {
    return true;
}

function closeSession() {
    return true;
}

function readSession($id) {
    global $conn;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT data FROM sessions WHERE id = ? AND last_accessed > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        return $row['data'];
    }

    return '';
}

function writeSession($id, $data) {
    global $conn;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("REPLACE INTO sessions (id, data, last_accessed) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $id, $data);
    return $stmt->execute();
}

function destroySession($id) {
    global $conn;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
    return $stmt->execute();
}

function gcSession($maxlifetime) {
    global $conn;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE last_accessed < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ? SECOND)");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $maxlifetime);
    return $stmt->execute();
}

if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();

    // Generate CSRF token only if it's not already set
    if (!isset($_SESSION['csrf_token'])) {
        $_SESSION['csrf_token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
    }
}

tauth.php:
<?php
// tauth.php
if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

if (empty($_SESSION['csrf_token'])) {
    $_SESSION['csrf_token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
}

require_once 'session_handler.php'; 
require_once 'db_connect.php'; 
require_once 'check_auth.php';

try {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        header("Location: login.php");
        exit();
    }

    $conn = getDatabaseConnection();
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $user = $result->fetch_assoc();

        $_SESSION['first_name'] = htmlspecialchars($user['first_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $_SESSION['last_name'] = htmlspecialchars($user['last_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $_SESSION['username'] = htmlspecialchars($user['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $_SESSION['email'] = htmlspecialchars($user['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $_SESSION['phone_number'] = htmlspecialchars($user['phone_number'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $_SESSION['title'] = htmlspecialchars($user['title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

        $roles = [
            'teacher' => 'Teacher',
            'assistant' => 'Assistant'
        ];

        if (array_key_exists($user['title'], $roles)) {
            $_SESSION['title'] = $roles[$user['title']];
        } else {
            error_log("Undefined account type for teacher with ID: $user_id");
            header("Location: error_page.php");
            exit();
        }

    } else {
        setcookie('remember_me_selector', '', time() - 3600, '/', '', true, true);
        setcookie('remember_me_authenticator', '', time() - 3600, '/', '', true, true);
        header("Location: login.php");
        exit();
    }

    session_regenerate_id(true);

    $stmt->close();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log("Error fetching teacher data: {$e->getMessage()}");
    $errorMessage = "Something went wrong while logging in. Please try again later.!";
    header("Location: error_page.php?error=" . urlencode($errorMessage));
    exit();
}

I tried to remove some of CSRF blocks of code or adding some to maintain the system but it went into problems and didn't solve the "Invalid CSRF Token" problem.
also tried to remove including unwanted files into pages to fix it but there is no way to fix the problem.
